# Можно ли загрузить и исполнить на C коде бит-код LLVM?

Tags: c, llvm

Можно ли загрузить и исполнить на C коде бит-код LLVM?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду? Загрузка биткода LLVM во время выполнения из программы написанной на Си?

Comment: Ваш биткод как-то слух режет, говорите как все - байткод.

Answer (score 5):

Вам в любом случае придётся применить либо AOT или JIT-компиляцию. Соответственно, придётся тащить либо ту, либо другую реализацию на борту.